# How to perform jQuery regular expression for finding all HTML entities for right arrows &rarr; on my site and adding a class?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I would like to perform a regular expression in jQuery to find all the HTML right arrow entities → on my site and add a class of "arrow-style". My CSS class of "arrow-style" has a specific font that is different from the other fonts used, hence why I just want to select just the arrow entity so I can style it.

These are what I mean by HTML entities: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp
(please search for arrow)

For example, I would like the following to be queried throughout my site and have a class added to it. However, I cannot simply select all `<a>` as these arrow entities are in a variety of HTML markup (they're not just in `<a>` tags)

```
<a href="#">Learn More &rarr;</a>
```

Output should be:

```
<a href="#">Learn More <span class="arrow-style">&rarr;</span></a>
```

Comment: Can you give an example to such elements?

Comment: @gdoron - please see question updates. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
​$("body *")​​​.html(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/(→)/g, "<span class='arrow-style'>$1</span>");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yga64/

Comment: +1, Though I believe he wants to add the container a class, not surround it with a new span. and it's very hard to produce it with regex.

Comment: @gdoron Yep, might be like that: http://jsfiddle.net/yga64/1/. However, it will add class to all parents of the element. The solution should be deeper (with textNodes, nodeTypes etc).

Comment: Would `​$("body")​​​...` be better? As it stands the function and the replace will be executed once for every element in the DOM. In more complex/real scenarios that would cause a lot of unnecessary searching and replacing, with the same text-elements being processed several times. See the console on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/yga64/2/

Comment: @Supr. Not doing such things is even better. Poor design makes you use such things.

Comment: @Supr no - serialising the whole DOM and then deserialising it again just to wrap an element is just _wrong_ !

Comment: @Alnitak That's a good question. I also don't think iterating though all elements will boost the performance. However, I might be wrong.

Comment: @VisioN the problem with _not_ iterating over all the elements is that using `.html()` will de-register any event handlers.

Comment: @Alnitak True but still it won't help in case of nesting like here: http://jsfiddle.net/yga64/3/. Again there are two ways: textNodes/nodeTypes or setting event handlers after replacement. Anyway, let the `*` selector remains: both solutions are not universal, hence are crap somehow.

Comment: @Alnitak, `​$("body *")` will also serialize/deserialize the whole DOM. The difference is that `​$("body")` only does it once for the entire DOM, while the original does it once for every element in the tree, causing the same html to be serialized, replaced, and deserialized several times over. See http://jsperf.com/search-and-replace